# C: preprocessor macro to build and use string literals at compile time?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, string-literals

I have a C function I am using to format strings that has the following signature:

```
int
string_format
(   char*       dst
,   const char* fmt
,   ...
);
```

I usually call it like:

```
char buf[20];
const char* name = "Jeff";
string_format ( buf , "Hello %s!\n" , name );
```

I am now trying to work with colored text using ANSI color codes. Ideally, I want to use them in my string literals like this:

```
char buf[20];
const char* name = "Jeff";
string_format ( buf , COLOR_RED "Hello %s!\n" , name );
```

I wrote some macros to build these string literals, but I have done something wrong. For example, I tried:

```
#define ANSI_CC(color) "\033["#color"m"
#define ANSI_CC_FG_RED "91"

#define COLOR_RED (ANSI_CC(ANSI_CC_FG_RED))
```

But when I try to call `string_format (buf, COLOR_RED "Hello world.\n"")`, I get a compiler error:

```
error: expected ')' before string constant
    |     COLOR_RED "Hello world.\n"
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

My thought was that the preprocessor would evaluate `COLOR_RED` down to this:

```
COLOR_RED                 =>
(ANSI_CC(ANSI_CC_FG_RED)) =>
"\033["ANSI_CC_FG_RED"m"  =>
"\033[""91""m"
```

But obviously it is doing something else instead, which I do not understand; I suspect I used the `#` stringify operator incorrectly. Could someone please explain what the preprocessor is doing with the macros I wrote? Also, if what I want to accomplish is possible, what do I need to change?

Thanks.

Comment: The outer parentheses in the `COLOR_RED` macro will be included in the macro expansion. Change it to `ANSI_CC(ANSI_CC_FG_RED)`.

Comment: Also please note that all major compilers have options to stop compilation after preprocessing, so you can actually see how all macros were expanded. When you have problems like this, I suggest you use it to see exactly what code the compiler will see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your macro will be expanded to:

```
string_format ( buf , ("\033[""ANSI_CC_FG_RED""m") "Hello %s!\n" , name );
```

You need to change the macro to:

```
#define ANSI_CC(color) "\033[" color "m"
#define ANSI_CC_FG_RED "91"

#define COLOR_RED ANSI_CC(ANSI_CC_FG_RED)
```

and it will be expanded to:

```
string_format ( buf , "\033[" "91" "m" "Hello %s!\n" , name );
```

https://godbolt.org/z/3oGzhhbYx